# Equivalent parameter of period property of Spring ScheduledExecutorTask in Spring ThreadPoolTaskExecutor class

Tags: java, spring, spring-scheduled

I want to replace  Spring ScheduledExecutorTask job with Spring ThreadPoolTaskExecutor implementation. Currently  my ScheduledExecutorTask job is running in every 120000ms(2 min), it is configured in job using period property of ScheduledExecutorTask class. Can you please tell me the equivalent parameter of it in Spring  ThreadPoolTaskExecutor class. Now I want to create a ThreadPoolTaskExecutor job and execute itin every 2 minutes.

```
<bean id="serviceScheduledTask"
      class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorTask">
    <property name="period" value="120000"/>
    <property name="runnable" ref="ServiceCacheManager"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: You'll want a `ThreadPoolTaskScheduler`, not a `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor`. You'll need to schedule a runnable yourself, in code.